# Nontrivial integral involving Hilbert Transform

Tags: integration

I am trying to compute the following integral:

$$\int \mathbb{H}(y_x(s)) \ ds$$

where 
$$\mathbb{H}(F)=PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{F(x')}{x-x'}\ dx'$$
is the Hilbert transform, and $PV$ means we are to take the principal value of the integral. Finally, $s$ is a contour moving along the characteristic $s= x-yt$.

Next, $y=y(x,t)$ is a solution to the inviscid Burger's equation, i.e.

$$y_t + yy_x = 0,$$
which has solution $y=f(x-yt)$ for $f(x)$ the initial condition at $t=0$.

The hard part is dealing with the derivative $y_x$, as $y_x = f'(x-yt)(1-ty_x)$.

Does anyone have any insight into handling this, before I turn to numerics?

Comment: I think I accidentally flagged this! Sorry if I did...completely unintentional